# Search by belongs_to custom foreign_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, has-many, belongs-to

I try to search for a match via the 2 teams, I tried several syntax, but nothing helps ...

Model Match:

```
class Match < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :home, class_name: 'Team', foreign_key: :home_id
  belongs_to :away, class_name: 'Team', foreign_key: :away_id
end
```

Model Team:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :home_matches, class_name: 'Match', foreign_key: :home_id
  has_many :away_matches, class_name: 'Match', foreign_key: :away_id

  # Fields: name
end
```

I tried something like this:

```
 Match.includes(:home, :away).where(homes: { name: 'Germany' }, aways: {name: 'China'})
```

Error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing
>   FROM-clause entry for table "homes")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1.**

Inspect in Rails Console query `puts Match.joins(:home, :away).to_sql`.
You could get result like:

```
SELECT "matches".* FROM "matches" INNER JOIN "teams" ON "teams"."id" = "matches"."home_id" INNER JOIN "teams" "away_matches" ON "away_matches"."id" = "matches"."away_id"
```

If so, use query like

```
Match.joins(:home, :away).where(teams: { name: 'Germany' }, away_matches: {name: 'China'})
```

**Option 2.**

Try query like

```
Match.where(home: Team.where(name: 'Germany'), away: Team.where(name: 'China'))
```

You can also pre-find ids of Teams:

```
home_id = Team.find_by(name: 'Germany').id
away_id = Team.find_by(name: 'China').id
Match.where(home_id: home_id, away_id: away_id)
```

Comment: First option `Match.joins(:home, :away).where(teams: { name: 'Germany' }, away_matches: {name: 'China'})` dosent work and second option yes

Comment: @BorisBRESCIANI Option 1 query depends on what `puts Match.joins(:home, :away).to_sql` exactly shows(it may depend on the Rails version).